# ckeditor-ckfinder default attributes (width and height) to uploaded images

Tags: php, ckeditor, ckfinder

When I upload images using ckfinder in the ckeditor the image displays nicely using css width & height. I would like images to have default width and height attributes. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Answered on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057938/ckfinder-image-resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, CKFinder just uploads the file to the server, and does not changes its resolution! You can however, use/create a plugin for CKEditor to change the image width & height when using the image dialog of CKEditor!

Btw: That dialog allows you to change the width and height of the selected image before placing it in your *"document"*! The values that are placed there by CKEditor are the real width & height of the selected image!

Comment: After selecting or uploading an image the user can change the width and height. I want it to automatically resize the image to the width and height the user sets. Is that possible?

I thaught that the ajax image resizer would fix that but can't get it to work. Somebody has experience with an automatic width and height resize-plugin?

In my config file of ckfinder I've got:

include_once "plugins/imageresize/plugin.php";

in the config.js I've got:

CKFinder.customConfig = function( config )
{
 config.extraPlugins = 'imageresize';
};

greetings and many thanks or the help !!!

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057938/ckfinder-image-resize

Answer (score 3):

Set the default width and height while clicking "ok" button.
 Replace the user entered height & width values with default height & width (Override "OnOK" Function)

In config.js

```
 CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {

    var dialogName = ev.data.name,
        dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if (dialogName == 'image') {
        var onOk = dialogDefinition.onOk;

        dialogDefinition.onOk = function (e) {
            var width = this.getContentElement('info', 'txtWidth');
            width.setValue('200');//Set Default Width

            var height = this.getContentElement('info', 'txtHeight');
            height.setValue('200');////Set Default height

            onOk && onOk.apply(this, e);
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the output_html.html in the _samples folder

Comment: the output_html doensn't explain manipulation of the img tag, attributes,styles...

Comment: Yes it does. Look under this comment:  // Output properties as attributes, not styles.

Answer (score 0):

In the **image.js** which is in *plugins/image/dialogs* folder of the CKEDITOR

there are two lines:

```
d&&d.setValue(b.$.width);
e&&e.setValue(b.$.height);
```

If you change `b.$.width` and `b.$.height` with numbers or **null**, you will have default values upon upload of any image size.

For example:

```
d&&d.setValue(600);
e&&e.setValue(null);
```

Will insert an image with 600px width and proportional height.
Remember to duplicate your **image.js** before editing it.