# CKFinder - how to use imageresize plugin?

Tags: ckfinder

Can anyone give me any tips, or point to documentation, on how to use the imageresize plugin for CKFinder, I can find nothing on this at all?

Thanks,

Toby

Comment: Its pretty straightforward. However CKFinder comes in multiple langauges. whatare you using? PHP/.NET/Coldfusion/ASP ?

Comment: Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057938/ckfinder-image-resize

Comment: I don't think there really is any documentation and I don't think that you can even affect the way it works, so there is no real configuration either. I would consider imageresize to be more like a core component rather than a plugin to be honest just because of the lack of configurable options and documentation.

http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/PHP/Configuration/Images This contains some info at least.

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation for multiple langauges at [docs.cksource.com](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide) Each language has a short intro on how to configure the ImageResize plugin. If you can confirm the langauge you are using, I'm sure you get more help

Comment: Cheers for trying to help Darren - we're using PHP; if you could point me at a starting point in the docs that would be great, I don't know why but I'm finding it really difficult to discover anything?!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the PHP version, so:

1) In config.php make sure that the plugin is actually enabled:

```
include_once "plugins/imageresize/plugin.php";
```

2) Make sure that some predefined sizes for thumbnails are set:

```
$config['plugin_imageresize']['smallThumb'] = '90x90';
$config['plugin_imageresize']['mediumThumb'] = '120x120';
$config['plugin_imageresize']['largeThumb'] = '180x180';
```

3) To verify that it works, just upload an image, right-click on it and in the context menu select "Resize". A dialog window that let's you resize an image should show up. You may even try it here: http://cksource.com/ckfinder/demo