# prevent CKEDITOR from adding image dimensions as a style

Tags: css, image, ckeditor

In ckeditor: Is there a way to get the width and height attributes instead of css style attribute for the image dimensions?

Comment: Can you clarify what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I *think* this has been asked before and the answer was yes, but only by changing the image plugin. Can't find the dupe right now though.

Comment: i would like to have width and height attributes instead of style="width:100;height:75".

Comment: i know i found some posts about it but allways regarding the older fckeditor

Comment: You mean *inline* styling of width and height, instead of declaring it in CSS?

Comment: no i do not want any css also not inline. ckeditor generates xhtml where the width and heightare specified using inline css styles. I want the good old width and height attributes because i'm using ckeditor as a newsletter maker and some clients like outlook do not support inline css width and height on images...

Answer (score 0):

As I said in [ckeditor-ckfinder default attributes (width and height) to uploaded images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049692/ckeditor-ckfinder-default-attributes-width-and-height-to-uploaded-images) the output_html.html sample shows how to use attributes and not styles for the dimensions.